# Java 17 spring boot app throws exception from GaloisCounterMode when starting in debug

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm using spring boot to create my service which has a mongodb connection to Atlas. Everytime I enter debug (I can assume this happens even when I'm not debugging) I get this exception from GaloisCounterMode.java: Must use either different key or  iv for GCM encryption

I have tracked the issue in the stack trace(in debug) that this exception happens because of Mongodb. Now, this exception does not break the service (the apps works perfectly fine), but I'd like to get rid of it. I can see that it tries to run this specific line of code from InternalStreamConnectionInitializer

```
`helloResult = CommandHelper.executeCommand("admin", helloCommandDocument, this.clusterConnectionMode, this.serverApi, internalConnection);`
```

which leads all the way to my Exception.

This is my dependency list:

```
`<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
            <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20231013</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- remove transient vulnerability from spring-cloud-aws-core        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.634</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- remove transient vulnerability from spring-cloud-aws-core        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>`
```

This is the only dependency in my pom about mongo

```
`<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>`
```

and this is my application.yml

```
`spring:
  security:
    basic:
      ignored: /**
      enable: false
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb+srv://user:pass@mydb.kpca12o.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
      database: my_database
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      file-size-threshold: 50MB
      max-file-size: 30MB
      max-request-size: 60MB`
```

I have this exact yaml configuration in other services as well and they don't throw any exception. The same mongo dependency in other places as well.

If anybody has any clue or ideas, please share them with me.

I tried removing all classes (apart from the main class annotated with @SpringBootApplication) and also removing and adding dependencies to see if that would change anything, but to no avail. I have also updated my sdk to corretto-17.0.9.